# Can't show different messages for unsupported file format using PrimeNg FileUpload Component

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the FileUpload component by PrimeNg, and I am only accepting PDF format for uploads. So I have a scenario where lets for example I have 3 files FileA.doc, FileB.pdf, FileC.doc. So I have 3 files out of which only one is of acceptable format. When I drag and drop to upload I get notified for only one file that is FileA and FileB can be seen for uploading but I don't see anything for FileB, which from the end user perspective can be a bit confusing whether it has been uploaded or upload has failed.

[image: This is how it shows for FileA Failing and FileB uploading but no status for FileC]

What I have tried is that I have tried to have a look at the upload events but couldn't extract anything from here where I could show message or even console log for each file and its upload status or a status regarding its acceptance for the upload criteria.
Below is my code :

HTML

```
<div class="card">
    <p-card header="Upload Report here">
        <p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" 
        [customUpload]="true" 
        [multiple]="multiple" 
        [auto]="true"
        (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" 
        (onError)="onError($event)" 
        (onRemove)="onRemove($event)"
        (uploadHandler)="handleUpload($event)"
        accept=".pdf">
        </p-fileUpload>
    </p-card>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
  onUpload(event) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
      this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
      this.msgs = [{severity:'success', summary:'Successfully uploaded', detail:`Files uploaded are : ${file.name}`}]
    }
  }

  handleUpload(event) {
    console.log(event);
    
  }

  onError(event) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
      this.msgs = [{severity:'error', summary:'Upload Failed ', detail:`Name of the file : "${file.name}"`}]
    }
  }

  onRemove(event) {
    this.msgs = [{severity:'info', summary:'File Removed ', detail:`Name of the file : "${event.file.name}"`}]
  }
```

Below is the information which I get when I debug it for the event.
[image: [![Debug Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKAVy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKAVy.png)]

But I get this information for only the accepted file format which is PDF and I can't see the other two Files i.e FileA and FileB which are unsupported files in the event log.

Answer (score 0):

if you provide accept=".pdf" in html and try to upload other file types 'onUpload' event is not getting triggered. So if you want to show user the message file type is not supported, remove accept=".pdf" from html. Instead check this condition on .ts file 'onUpload' event .

```
onUpload(event) {
for (let file of event.files) {
  const acceptedFormats = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 
'application/pdf'];

  if (file && !acceptedFormats.includes(file.type)) {
    alert('Invalid file format. Please upload a valid file.');
    return;
  }
    this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
    this.msgs = [{severity:'success', summary:'Successfully uploaded', detail:`Files uploaded are : ${file.name}`}]
}
```

}